# In stability analysis how to construct the jacobian matrix?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, jacobian, stability-theory

I'm a bit confused if we have $\dfrac{dx}{dt}=z+3y+x^2$ and $\dfrac{dy}{dt}=z^2$ what will be the components of the Jacobian matrix?

Comment: Jacobian of what?

Comment: as @Moo said something is missing in the problem

Comment: Let's make it a bit clear. if we have two functions: first one depends only on x, second one depends on y and r. What will be the jacobian matrix for this case? I'm applying stability analysis to some physical system but I'm confused on constructing the jacobian. Hope it's clear now.